# zuul clone gerrit repository when event triggered?how to stop this?

Tags: gerrit, gerrit-trigger, zuul-ci

Every time patchset-created event triggered, zuul clone the whole repository.
how to stop this? because it takes a too long time and makes job starts very slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the expected way Git plugin works. Go to the job configuration > Source Code Management > Git > Additional Behaviours, and see if the "Wipe out repository & force clone" option is set like in the following example:

[image]